# If we know both $G/e$ and $G−e$, do we know the initial graph?

Tags: graph-theory

My question is as follows:

Let $e$ be an edge of $G$. Suppose that we know both $G/e$ and $G-e$, do we know the initial graph?

After some thinking, I figured out how to generate some examples where we do not know the initial graph despite knowing both $G/e$ and $G-e$.

Let $G$ be a graph with $V(G)={v_1,v_2,...,v_n}$. Let $G_1=G+uv_i$ and $G_2+uv_j$, where $i\neq j$. Then, we have created two graphs which are very likely non-isomorphic but have the same $G/e$ and $G-e$, where $e$ is $uv_i$ and $uv_j$ in $G_1$ and $G_2$, respectively.

This got me thinking if these are the only examples to this problem. Can my fellow Mathematicians help me find other new examples or prove that these are the only examples? Thanks!

PS: For those who are wondering why I consider $G/e$ and $G-e$, my motivation behind this question was the deletion-contraction formula.

Answer (score 4):

ANSWER: in general, we don't.

Here is a counter-example, two mini-combs $\ A\ $ and $\ B$:

**EXAMPLE 0.** Let:

$$ X\ :=\ \{\{0\ 1\}\ \{1\ 2\}\ \{2\ 3\}\ \{3\ 4\}\}\ \cup
         \ \{\{1\ a\}\ \{2\ b\}\ \{3\ c\}\} $$

$$ A\ :=\ X\cup \{\{a\ \ \alpha\}\} $$

$$ B\ :=\ X\cup \{\{b\ \ \beta\}\} $$

These were the edges. The vertices are:

$$ V_A\ :=\ \{0\ 1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ a\ b\ c\ \alpha\} $$

[image]

and

$$ V_B\ :=\ \{0\ 1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ a\ b\ c\ \beta\} $$

[image]

The edges to be removed are $\ \{a\ \alpha\}\ $
and $\ \{b\ \beta\}\ $ respectively.

---

---

**Remark**: By a kind of doubling my combs (not quite) one can
get an example without without any vertex of degree 1.

---

---

FURTHER EXAMPLES

**EXAMPLE 1.** This one is simpler. Let's concentrate on the edges:

$$ Y\ :=\ \{\{1\ 2\}\ \{2\ 3\}\ \{3\ 4\}\ \{3\ c\}\} $$

$$ A\ := \{\{0\ 1\}\} \cup Y $$

[image]

$$ B\ :=\ Y\cup\{\{4\ 5\}\} $$

[image]

The vertices are

$$ V_A\ :=\ \{0\ 1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ c\} $$
$$ V_B\ :=\ \{1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ c\} $$

The edges to be removed are $\ \{0\ 1\}\ $ and $\ \{4\ 5\}\ $
respectively.

---

---

[A new and a correct EXAMPLE 2 to be inserted here later].

An update 2023-06-10: it's not clear to me anymore that such examples exist where degree of each vertex is greater than 1. There seem to be some obstructions.

Comment: Also, MO LATeX doesn't display "\," properly as a short space in the answers (but here, in the comment, it does so: $I\,\ I\,I $.

Comment: Both the braces and the spaces look fine to me.

Comment: I am glad. However, I don't see them.

Comment: Hmm, now I see everything's fine. A mystery. :-)

Comment: @WlodAA I don't quite understand what you mean when you say that $A:=X\cup \{\{a,A\}\}$? Do you mean that the edges of $A$ is $X\cup \{\{a,A\}\}$?

Comment: An incidental coincidence  two A's -- I'll fix it.

Comment: @Explorer1234, it's fixed -- the example is as simple as possible (even if I didn't shoot at any minimality record).

Comment: Would someone provide an illustration of these two comb-graphs, please, pretty please? (As I said, it is totally simple).

Comment: @WlodAA This looks like an example of the type given by the OP, with $u=\alpha=\beta$ and $v_i = a$ and $v_j = b$.

Comment: @TimothyChow, I don't see anything in the OT's post but a tautological general format for any counterexample, not any example.

Comment: @WlodAA The OP gives a specific construction, not a "tautological general format." One starts with a graph $G$ (which in your case is $X$), then adds a pendant edge in 2 different ways; in case 1, one attaches an edge to $v_i$ to get a graph $G_1 = G + uv_i$ (in your case, one attaches an edge to $a$ to get a graph $A = X+\alpha a$) and in case 2, one attaches an edge to $v_j$ to get a graph $G_2 = G + uv_j$ (in your case, one attaches an edge to $b$ to get a graph $B = X+\beta b$). This is not a "tautological general format" because $G_1$ and $G_2$ both have at least one vertex of degree 1.

Comment: @TimothyChow, I see, I am a sloppy reader. I apologize to OT and to you. Now, I am confused, what the question was about?

Comment: OK, I am not confused anymore, yes, there are a lot of different examples, I'll add some of them.

Comment: @WlodAA Can you give more elaboration on what you mean by "doubling my combs"? What are the explicit vertices and edges?

Comment: I meant to write the next exmaples along this line but MO LaTeX tortures me and I had to take a break. I'll rest a bit and will write it in the total detail.

Comment: @WlodAA In your EXAMPLE 2, the contractions are isomorphic to each other, but the deletions are not.

Comment: @TimothyChow, right, thank you for pointing it out. I'll replace my present wrong Example 2 by a correct one, I hope.

Comment: @WlodAA I have added the graphs to your examples. FYI, I used sagemath to draw these graphs. With the following codes:

Comment: G = Graph({0: [1], 1: [0,2,'a'], 2:[1,3,'b'], 3: [2,4,'c'], 'a': [u'\u03B1']})
G.show()

Comment: H = Graph({0: [1], 1: [0,2,'a'], 2:[1,3,'b'], 3: [2,4,'c'], 'b': [u'\u03B2']})
H.show()

Comment: G = Graph({0: [1], 1: [0,2], 2: [1,3], 3:[2,4,'c']})
G.show()

Comment: H = Graph({1: [2], 2: [1,3], 3:[2,4,'c'], 4: [5]})
H.show()

Comment: @Explorer1234, many thanks for adding the graphs to my "Answer".

Answer (score 3):

Since the [Tutte polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial) is universal for deletion–contraction invariants, a good way to look for examples of what you're looking for is to search for non-isomorphic graphs with the same Tutte polynomial.

I'm not sure if, when you contract, you reduce multiple edges to a single edge.  If you do, then consider the final pair of graphs given by [Aaron Dall on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3257432/), neither of which contains a vertex of degree 1.  Delete/contract the edge $\mathsf{dg}$ of the first graph, and delete/contract the edge $\mathsf{eg}$ on the second graph.

[image]

[image]

Comment: (Somehow, my comment has vanished, let me try again). Tim, you always write clearly but -- to me -- not on this occasion. BTW, for the sake of our ancient AA and on sci.mth meetings, could you, if you can, provide a graphical rendition of my two comb-graphs?

Comment: @WlodAA I don't have an easy way to draw graphs. I stole these graphs from Aaron Dall's math.SE answer.

Comment: @Timothy Chow, thank you for letting me know. Computers give me hard time. I love them and they hate me.

Comment: More generally there is the operation of "Whitney twists" on graphs, which preserves not just the Tutte polynomial but the (graphic) matroid. In fact I think it is a theorem of Whitney that two graphs (with some adjectives attached, maybe "2-connected") that have the same matroid are related by a series of Whitney twists.